# Can't find bundle for base name org.example.module.MessagesBundle, locale en

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, resourcebundle

For first time, I'm using Intellij IDEA for setting up my first Gradle project. I'm seeing the following error while reading data from resource bundle.

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.example.module.MessagesBundle, locale en
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1581)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1396)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:854)
    at org.example.Main.getMessageFromBundle(Main.java:19)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

I'm adding sample code from project.

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anJUm.png)

Main class

```
/*
 * This Java source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package org.example;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        System.out.println(getMessageFromBundle("MYCODE01", "org.example.module"));
    }

    private static String getMessageFromBundle(String code, String resourceBundle) {

        try {

            ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(resourceBundle + ".MessagesBundle", Locale.ENGLISH);
            return bundle.getString(code);

        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return  "";
        }
    }
}
```

Resource bundle

```
MYCODE01=My test message
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I tried the following things to resolve missing resource bundle issue. But issue remains same.

1. Added source root in build.gradle

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

2. Added source root in build.gradle

```
compileJava {
    sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
    sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
    sourceSets.test.resources.srcDirs = ['src/test/resources']
}
```

3. Restructured project
   [Restructured project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6pQU.png)